# Inserting multiple data into one table

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

How to insert multiple data in the database? when I insert data that has multiple orders, only one item is inserted in the database. I need help putting this into a loop.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_items){
    $item_id = $each_items['item_id'];
    $quantity = $each_items['quantity'] ;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = '$item_id'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $product_name = $row['name'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $total_price = $price * $quantity;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer_order(
    id,quantity,item_id,
    total_price,shipping_address,
    shipping_date,customer_id)
    VALUES ('','$quantity','$item_id','$total_price',
    '','',
    '$lastId')") or die (mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Here's what I tried but it's generating a syntax error:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_items){
    $item_id = $each_items['item_id'];
    $item_id_count = count($item_id) ;
    $quantity = $each_items['quantity'] ;
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = '$item_id'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
       $product_name = $row['name'];
       $price = $row['price'];
       $total_price = $price * $quantity;
       foreach($i=0,$i < $item_id_count,$i++){
          mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer_order(
          id,quantity,item_id,
          total_price,shipping_address,
          shipping_date,customer_id)
          VALUES ('','$quantity','$item_id','$total_price',
          '','',
          '$lastId')") or die (mysql_error());
       }
    }
}
```

How can I correctly write the loop?

Comment: What's the error message? Also, [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @JohnConde . there is no error message ,it just happen that only one item is inserted in the table, although i choose multiple items.

Comment: "Here's what i did but it gives me syntax error," <-- what is the syntax error?

Comment: foreach($i=0,$i < $item_id_count,$i++).. it gives me syntax error in this line

Answer (score 0):

You have written `foreach($i=0,$i < $item_id_count,$i++)` where I think you meant

```
for ($i=0 ; $i < $item_id_count ; $i++ )
```